# FastApi return dictionary with tuple as key: error unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, set, fastapi

I am trying to create an endpoint in FastAPI that returns this dictionary:

```
return {("string1", "string2"): "a"}
```

but it fails with:
`unhashable type: 'list'`

also

```
return {set(["string1", "string2"]): "a"}
```

fails with:
`unhashable type: 'set'`

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A tuple can function as a dict key; that's not causing the error. There is something you're not showing us (for example, the traceback), and/or FastAPI converts tuples into lists behind the scenes (again, the traceback might show such information).

Comment: if I change that one single line to 
`return {"string1": "a"}`  everything works tho.

--- What you mentioned is right tho:
The traceback mentions a "jsonable_encoder" .

```return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "......../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 109, in jsonable_encoder
    encoded_dict[encoded_key] = encoded_value```

from memory json does not allow a set as a dictionary key, so you are probably right there, I need to connect the dots now, will report on findings

Comment: sets and tuples don't exist in JSON. But then again, if it's converted to JSON (where a tuple will be translated to a JSON list), it would need to be converted back to a Python dict/list before this error can occur. Which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suppose the answer here was: you can have a set as a key to a dictionary, but not a list. As sets and tuples don't exist in JSON,  a tuple will be translated to a JSON list. But a list cannot be a key to a dictionary, hence the error returned.

Comment: Sure, that's correct. And you can have a tuple as a dict key as well. But, that implies that your Python structure was translated to JSON, and then back to Python. Which is odd, if it's served to a client: just Python -> JSON -> client (handles the JSON) is enough. There is no need, i.m.o., to convert the JSON (back) to Python. That's why I mentioned "something going on behind the scenes", that currently, I can't explain nor seems to make sense to me.